# How to set up different authentication for API and UI

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NetCore 2.2 (probably moving to 3.0 soon).  I have an Azure App Service application.

I want to have an API that clients will use an API token (client secret) to authenticate with so that they can run without requiring interactive authorization.

The UI portion will require Azure Active Directory authentication.

How do I wire this up these two different auth methods my ASP.Net Core app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How-to

1. Firstly, we need an **AuthenticationHandler** & **Options** to authenticate request with an API Token(Client Secret). Suppose you've created such an Authentication Handler & Options:

   ```cs
   public class ClientSecretAuthenOpts : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
   {
       public const string DefaultAuthenticationSchemeName = "ClientSecret";
   }

   public class ClientSecretAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<ClientSecretAuthenOpts>
   {
       public ClientSecretAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<ClientSecretAuthenOpts> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) 
           : base(options, logger, encoder, clock) { }

       protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
       {
           // ... authenticate request 
       }
   }
   ```
2. And then **register multiple Authentication Schemes one by one**:

   ```cs
   // add mulitple authentication schemes
   services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)           // set AzureAD as the default for users (using the UI)
       .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAD", options))         // setup AzureAD Authentication
       .AddScheme<ClientSecretAuthenOpts,ClientSecretAuthenticationHandler>(  // setup ClientSecret Authentication
           ClientSecretAuthenOpts.DefaultAuthenticationSchemeName,
           opts=>{ }
       );

   // post configuration for OIDC
   services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>{
       options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";         // Microsoft identity platform
       options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false; // accept several tenants 
   });
   ```
3. Finally, in order to enable **multiple authentication schemes** at the same time, we need **override the default policy**:

   ```cs
   services.AddAuthorization(opts => {
       // allow AzureAD & our own ClientSecret Authentication at the same time
       var pb = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
           ClientSecretAuthenOpts.DefaultAuthenticationSchemeName,
           "AzureAD"
       );  
       opts.DefaultPolicy = pb.RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
   });
   ```

#### Demo & Test

Suppose your API token (client secret) is sent in Request Header as below :

```
GET https://localhost:5001/Home/Privacy HTTP/1.1
Api-Subscription-Id: Smith
Api-Subscription-Key: top secret
```

To avoid hardcoding the header name, I create add two properties in the options:

```cs
public class ClientSecretAuthenOpts : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
{
    public const string DefaultAuthenticationSchemeName = "ClientSecret";
    public string ApiClientIdHeadername {get;set;}= "Api-Subscription-Id";
    public string ApiClientTokenHeaderName {get;set;}= "Api-Subscription-Key";
}
```

In order to authenticate above request, I create a custom Authentication Handler as below:

```cs
public class ClientSecretAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<ClientSecretAuthenOpts>
{
    public ClientSecretAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<ClientSecretAuthenOpts> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) 
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock) { }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        // if there's no header for Client ID & Client Sercet, skip
        if(
            Context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(Options.ApiClientIdHeadername, out var clientIdHeader) &&
            Context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(Options.ApiClientTokenHeaderName, out var clientSecretHeader) 
        ){
            // validate client's id & secret
            var clientId = clientIdHeader.FirstOrDefault();
            var clientKey = clientSecretHeader.FirstOrDefault();
            var (valid, id) = await ValidateApiKeyAsync(clientId, clientKey);

            if(!valid){
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail($"invalid token:{clientKey}");
            }else{
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(id);
                var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, new AuthenticationProperties(), this.Scheme.Name);
                return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
            }
        }
        return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
    }

    private Task<(bool, ClaimsIdentity)> ValidateApiKeyAsync(string clientId,string clientSecret)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity id = null;
        // fake: need check key against the Database or other service
        if(clientId=="Smith" && clientSecret == "top secret"){
            id = new ClaimsIdentity(
                new Claim[]{ 
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "client id from db or from the request"),
                    new Claim("Add Any Claim", "add the value as you like"),
                    // ... 
                }
                ,this.Scheme.Name
            );
            return Task.FromResult((true, id));
        }
        return Task.FromResult((false,id));
    }

}
```

**Test**

Let's say we have a controller Action annotated with the `[Authorize]` attribute

```cs
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    return Ok("hello,world");
}
```

When accessing the url within a browser (UI, without the header), the user will be redirected to Azure AD Authentication if he's not signed in.

When testing the above request with a client secret,

And we'll get the "hello,world" response:
[image]

Comment: How do you bind the client secret to `ClientSecretAuthenOpts` in Startup? Same way as IOptions?